# Q - Finding equivalent class to FBAppCall in newest SDK in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have recently upgraded FBSDK in my project an I struggle with finding equivalent class. Replacing old version with new version went smoothly with CocoaPods.
I have read needed parts of documentatiom about this deprecated class and upgrading from 3.x to 4.x.

There is my part of my delegate class:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)aApplication {

    [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActive];

(...)
```

}

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)aApplication openURL:(NSURL *)aUrl sourceApplication:(NSString *)aSourceApplication annotation:(id)aAnnotation {

    if ([aSourceApplication isEqualToString:@"com.facebook.Facebook"]) {

        BOOL urlWasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:aUrl sourceApplication:aSourceApplication fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {             

 (...)

     return urlWasHandled;

        }
```

And last but not least - I have put all three Libraries from newest FBSDK and imported them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActive]
```

becomes

```
[FBSDKAppEvents activateApp]
```

---

```
[FBAppCall handleOpenURL:aUrl sourceApplication:aSourceApplication fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) { ...
```

becomes

```
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
```